# Mysterious "this" g++ requirement

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, this

If you make a template class (or struct), and then inherit from it defining a class (struct), the following code is possible:

```
template <typename T>
struct Par
{
    T t;
};

struct Chl : public Par<int>
{
    void setT(int in) { t = in; }
};

int main()
{
    Chl c;
    c.setT(1);
}
```

However, if you make `Chl` a template too, like this

```
template <typename U>
struct Chl : public Par<U>
{
    void setT(U in) { t = in; }
};

int main()
{
    Chl<int> c;
    c.setT(1);
}
```

the compiler will give you an error:

```
error: ‘t’ was not declared in this scope
   12 |  void setT(U in) { t = in; }
```

To avoid it you have to define setT as follows:

```
void setT(U in) { this->t = in; }
```

and only then will it compile.

So it looks as if templating `Chl` creates some additional ambiguity which has to be resolved by `this`, but it doesn't seem to be the case (because the base struct has the same single field `t` in all cases). So why is `this` necessary (at least with g++)?

Comment: Template classes can be specialized.  Therefore, the compiler can not know that `t` means `this->t` for every possible base class `Par<U>`.